# How to implement a simple CRUD in Flutter for a Car class?

Tags: flutter, crud

I'm developing a Flutter application and I'm looking to implement basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations for a **`Car`** class that contains information such as the car's name and year of manufacture. I'd like to share my current approach and receive feedback on how to improve or optimize the code.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// Dart code for the Car class and CRUD operations


MAIN.dart

void main(){
  runApp(CarApp());
}


CAR.dart

class Car {
  final model;
  final year;

  Car(this.model,this.year);
}


LIST.dart

class CarList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Car> cars;

  CarList(this.cars);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lista de Carros'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cars.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(cars[index].model),
            subtitle: Text('Ano: ${cars[index].year.toString()}'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

CARAPP.dart

class CarApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarAppState createState() => _CarAppState();
}

class _CarAppState extends State<CarApp> {
  final List<Car> _cars = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cadastro de Carros',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Cadastro de Carros'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: _cars.isEmpty
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text('Nenhum carro cadastrado.'),
                    )
                  : CarList(_cars),
            ),
            CarForm(_addCar),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addCar(Car car) {
    setState(() {
      _cars.add(car);
    });
  }
}


FORM.dart

class CarForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Car) addCarCallback;

  CarForm(this.addCarCallback);

  @override
  _CarFormState createState() => _CarFormState();
}

class _CarFormState extends State<CarForm> {
  final TextEditingController _modelController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _yearController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _modelController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Modelo'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
          TextField(
            controller: _yearController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Ano de Fabricação'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _addCar();
            },
            child: Text('Cadastrar'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addCar() {
    final String model = _modelController.text;
    final int year = int.tryParse(_yearController.text) ?? 0;

    if (model.isNotEmpty && year != 0) {
      widget.addCarCallback(Car(model, year));

      _modelController.clear();
      _yearController.clear();
    }
  }
}


This code consists of a basic representation of a Flutter application that has a list of cars and allows adding, viewing, editing, and removing cars.

I would like to know if this is a good practice for implementing CRUD in Flutter for the Car class, or if there's a more efficient way to do this. Any suggestions or improvements are greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any guidance or advice!
```